# Why are files created in one branch present in another?

Tags: git

I want to be able to switch to different branches without the files which were created in one branch existing in another.

Here's a simple example.

```
$ git checkout -b feat1 && touch feat1 && git add feat1 && git commit -m "feat1" && git checkout master
$ git checkout -b feat2 && touch feat2 && git add feat2 && git commit -m "feat2" && git checkout master
$ git checkout -b feat3 && touch feat3 && git add feat3 && git commit -m "feat3" && git checkout master
```

I would like to open the repo directory in (Finder, Windows Explorer) and have the following behaviour.

```
$ git checkout master
```

Desired: have no files

Actual: has no files

```
$ git checkout feat1
```

Desired: only feat1 file exists

Actual: only feat1 file exists

```
$ git checkout feat2
```

Desired: only feat2 file exists

Actual: contains both feat1 and feat2

```
$ git checkout feat3
```

Desired: only feat3 file exists

Actual: contains feat1, feat2, and feat3

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: SOunds like you are trying to actually break the "branching" model. Branches are created so that changes are kept "independently" from each other. So, if you create a file in one branch and you switch to another, the file will **go**. If you want the file to _kind of magically_ stay on the other branch, you have to merge/cherry-pick from the other branch. Or make the branching model work for you: instead of creating all three branches from master, create feat2 from frat1 and create feat3 from feat2.

Comment: So you're saying that you're in a state *right now* where you don't see what you want, right?  Can you add the output of `git log --oneline --graph --pretty --decorate` to your question?

Comment: Each line ends with `git checkout master` which reverts back to the master branch where no files exists. Then you base each branch off of master which means the branches too start as empty, then you add 1 file to each branch and commit. Thus, each branch only contains the one file. If you want to base feat2 off of feat1, and thus contain the file from feat1, don't checkout master before creating the new branch.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Now I interpreted the question in the opposite of that. I understand it as asking why files created in feat1, were still there when checking out feat3. OP seems to want feat3 to *only* have the file `feat3`, but what they are experiencing instead is that branch feat3 has files `feat1`, `feat2`, and `feat3`.

Comment: Well, his question is full of contradiction. For instance, he can't check out master unless he made a commit on master, and thus there should exist at least one file on it to begin with. Additionally, he says that he has the following behavior: "only feat2 exists (actually contains feat1 & feat2)". So which is it? Does it contain only feat2? Or does it contain feat1 and feat2? He needs to clean up his question.

Comment: Or, as the answer implies, when the command executes to checkout master, it fails with an error, which really should be mentioned.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I do agree it is in need of some editing, and have thus submitted an edit to clarify things. But I'm not sure it's that full of contradiction. "I would like to open the reop directory in (Finder,windows explorer) and have the following behaviour." tells me that the following lines are about what behavior OP is looking for. The parts in parenthesis seem to be what is actually happening, hence the use of the word "actually". So "only feat2 exists (actually contains feat1 & feat2)" = OP wants only feat2, but is instead seeing both feat1 and feat2.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Well, it is *possible* to commit an empty tree. So that's not exactly a contradiction, but you'd have to go out of your way to set it up. It is part of why I suspect the repo doesn't even have a `master`.  Anyway, my reading of the "only feat2 exists (actually contains feat1 & feat2)" stuff was that he's saying what he *wants* to have, and in parens telling us what he's getting instead.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you run those commands then each branch will contain only the one file.

Did you run these commands immediately after a `git init` - i.e. on a repo with no commits?  In that case the final `git checkout master` on each line would fail, so `feat2` would be branched *from* `feat1`, etc. and you would see the cumulative set of files in each branch.

And in that case if you checkout `feat3` and do a log, you will see that the commits from `feat1` and `feat2` are in the history for the `feat3` commit.

That might be all that's wrong...